# Grouping in Solr 4 admin interface, where is grouping field?

Tags: solr

By the address:
http://myhost.com:8983/solr/#/collection1/query

I can not find the possibility for inputing GROUP queries, like:

**group=true&group.field=geohash1_st**

Where is fields for that type of query?

That is what I have:
[image]

P.S: I have solr 4 version.

P.S2: I can type my query into URL of my browser, but it is not convenient, because the query is long! So the question is to make that using prepared input fields...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place you'd put those is labelled "Raw Query Parameters" ... but it's not in your screenshot.  This probably means that you're not using a new enough version of Solr 4.  I can confirm that this is in the admin UI as of version 4.2.1, and it's definitely in the latest version, 4.6.0.

You disappeared from #solr before I could answer there.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will count that as correct if no other options will be given in a close time. It is strange that solr 4 does not have obvious field for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue.
I have done like this :

We need to send parameter on : **Raw Query Parameters**

```
stats.facet=Status&stats.field=ItemPrice&stats=on&wt=json
```

`stats.facet=Status` - It means group by Status.

`stats.field=ItemPrice` - It means Sum,min,max,sd.. macro aggregation will be done on ItemPrice.
`stats=on` It enable the stats

[image]

Result will contain Stats like below :

```
"stats":{
    "stats_fields":{
      "ItemPrice":{
        "min":1.0,
        "max":1399.99,
        "count":8,
        "missing":0,
        "sum":3147.9399999999987,
        "sumOfSquares":3063146.2605999997,
        "mean":393.49249999999984,
        "stddev":510.5257066635194,
        "facets":{
          "Status":{
            "6":{
              "min":1.0,
              "max":1399.99,
              "count":8,
              "missing":0,
              "sum":3147.9399999999987,
              "sumOfSquares":3063146.2605999997,
              "mean":393.49249999999984,
              "stddev":510.5257066635194}}}}}}}
```